# Why can't dynamically-typed function in Flutter return the correct type?

Tags: function, flutter, types, parameters

I have this function:

```
U on<T, U> (T value, T defaultValue, U Function (T value) builder) => builder(value ?? defaultValue);
```

If I use it like this:

```
var a = "Hello";
var b = "World";
final result = on(a, b, (value) => Text(value))
```

Inside the builder callback parameter, the value type is always dynamic. Why it can't have the same type as the parameter a and b?

Comment: clarification required: why do you assign "Hello" to an integer typed variable? You shoud instead use var a="Hellow";

Comment: @Darish fixed. I was using int examples at first, but then switch to string midway to make it easier to supply to Text widget.

Comment: event though the type is dynamic, it would not make any problem for you. You can cast it into actual type, say String for example. What problem are you facing?

Comment: `final result = on<String, Text>(a, b, (value) => Text(value));` will fix the issue

Comment: @Darish the problem is the typecast fails. (cannot convert dynamic into String, or something like that, which is why I asked this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dart currently does not support inference in parameter lists. This issue is being tracked however [#731](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/731).

Right now you would need to explicitly type this:

```
final result = on(a, b, (String value) => Text(value))
```

This at least enforces, that `a` `b` and the `builder` share the same type.

With the upcoming [`implicit-dynamic`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#enabling-additional-type-checks) analyzer rule, things like these will get spotted more easly and the increased maintance overhead hopefully lets the dart language maintainers reconsider the prioritization of the inference issue.

Comment: Oh okay, I don't know that you can enforce a type for the received value like that. Thanks!